What is the CLIPS C function equivalent to the CLIPS statement 'find-all-facts'?
Trying to create a rules file that I then load to evaluate in CLIPS from Swift, I am encountering the following error:
[PRNTUTIL1] Unable to find deftemplate 'message'.

The commented part of my code however works correctly.
////// testing.clp
(deftemplate message
    (slot value))

(defrule hello
    =>
    (assert (message (value "Hello world... from Swift!"))))

func test_CLIPS() {
    var cv = CLIPSValue()
    
    /* ////// THIS WORK OK!!!
    Eval(clipsEnv, "(clear)", nil)
    Build(clipsEnv, "(deftemplate message (slot value))")
    Build(clipsEnv, "(defrule hello => (assert (message (value \"\nFact Slot Retrieval... from Swift!\"))))")
    Eval(clipsEnv, "(reset)", nil)
    Eval(clipsEnv, "(run)", nil)
    Eval(clipsEnv, "(find-all-facts ((?f message)) TRUE)", &cv)
    */
    
    Clear(clipsEnv)
    c_load_rules(name: "testing", type: "clp") // Call CLIPS function Load()
    Reset(clipsEnv)
    Run(clipsEnv, -1)
    Eval(clipsEnv, "(find-all-facts ((?f message)) TRUE)", &cv) //?? CLIPS C equivalent exist/necessary??
    
    print(c_eval(cv: cv)) // Call CLIPS function FactSlotValue and return a string from "lexemeValue->contents"
}

Load testing.clp OK...

(deftemplate message
    (slot value))

(defrule hello
    =>
    (assert (message (value "Hello world... from Swift!"))))

I am trying to load a file with CLIPS templates and CLIPS rules and evaluate it inside an iOS application.

Are you asking us to write you a C function?  This is not a code-writing service, so if what you're looking for is non-trivial then that's unlikely to happen.  Are you asking for us to recommend a function already implemented in some library?  That would be explicitly off topic here.  Are you supposing that the function you are looking for would be provided by the C standard library?  I don't know what find-all-facts does, but based on its name alone, I'm inclined to doubt that an analogue exists in the standard library.

I found the problem. It was sending the contents of the CLIPS file instead of the path. Now it works.

The correct code is:
private func test_CLIPS() {        
    var cv = CLIPSValue()
    let fileURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testing", ofType: "clp")
        
    Clear(clipsEnv)
    Reset(clipsEnv)
    Load(clipsEnv, fileURL)
    Run(clipsEnv, -1)
    Eval(clipsEnv, "(find-all-facts ((?f message)) TRUE)", &cv)
        
    self.message = c_eval(cv: cv)
}

